# SQLite table name invalid characters

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite

I want to give name "http://192.168.1.2/abc/xyz_values" to a table in SQLite.

I am creating the table dynamically. How can i achieve this, as SQLite is not allowing me to create a table with this name?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So far as I know, the only legal characters for a SQLite table name are the upper/lower Roman alphanumerics plus underscore.

Comment: Though one reference suggests that simply enclosing the name in quotes will work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Choose a different name for your table. It is not possible.

Why does the name have to be like that in the first place? It sounds a little dodgy...

Answer (score 2):

use square brackets `[http://192.168.1.2/abc/xyz_values]` when creating your table

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods to create identifiers with special characters: double quotes, backticks, and square brackets.

Double quotes are standard SQL, while backticks and square brackets are supported only for compatibility with MySQL and SQL Server, so it's recommended to use the former:

```
CREATE TABLE "http://192.168.1.2/abc/xyz_values"(...)
```

Double quotes and backticks that occur inside the identifier can be escaped by doubling them; this is not possible with the closing square bracket:

```
CREATE TABLE """"(...)    -- table name is one double quote
```